# How do I choose between shredded and finely shredded cheddar cheese?

Tags: cheese, melting

I use shredded cheese for spur of the moment enchiladas or to top burgers with.  I learned the hard way that my supermarket store brand sharp cheddar does not melt well, so my next purchase will be for a mild cheddar. They have both "shredded" and "finely shredded" and I'm wondering what the optimal use case is for each. Obviously finely shredded will melt faster so I'm wondering is there any reason not to get that? (Btw, I know hand shredding block cheddar is best for melting but I like the convenience of having a bag of preshredded cheddar in the freezer I don't have to worry about molding over.)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to check for the lowest proportion of added anti-caking agent (here potato starch is used).  That's the reason it doesn't melt very well.

If you're going to freeze it, you could grate a large batch of a block you like and freeze that - the best of both worlds but a fair bit off effort in one go. If I was doing a lot I'd use the grater attachment for my food processor.